# How to retrieve model properties from an ember view, which was created inside an {{#each}}

Tags: ember.js

I'm having an issue retrieving properties from my model inside a view that was created from a template inside an {{#each}} loop for an array controller. Here is the snippet:

```
{{#each controller}}
    {{view MyApp.MyView}}
{{/each}}

MyApp.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var property = this.get('controller.property');

        console.log(property); // Outputs "undefined"
    }
});
```

When I've used `this.get('controller.property');` in the past, it has worked. However, now that I am using an ArrayController it does not seem to be working. Is there a way that I can access the current properties from the each loop inside the view code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the current item of the each helper, to the `content` property of the view, using the `this` keyword:

```
{{#each controller}}
    {{view MyApp.MyView contentBinding="this"}}
{{/each}}

MyApp.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var someObject = this.get('content');
        console.log(someObject);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, I think:

```
{{#each controller}}
    {{view MyApp.MyView}}
{{/each}}

MyApp.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var someObject = this.get('parentView.controller');
        console.log(someObject);
    }
});
```